# Change format and appearance of inbuilt calendar live tile

Tags: settings, calendars, tiles

I was wondering if we can change the date format of the calendar on the start screen. The current format "Tue 1" is pretty brief and I'd like to see a more detailed day/date format. Also, can we customize the appearance for this inbuilt calendar in Windows phone 7.5?

**EDIT**: Is there a good third party app that gives more options? All my previous phones had calendars that looked a lot better.

Comment: Do you mean for the live tile, or within the application itself?

Comment: The live tile. The one that occupies the entire width of the start screen

Answer (score 5):

There is no official way to do that. The calendar is a built in application, and is configured as to how Microsoft deems best according to the research and usability studies it has done.

#### What you can customize in the calendar (sorry, nothing for the live tile)

- The color for each calendar
- Show to-dos
- only show facebook events for those you have responded to.
- selectively turn off calendars for an account.

Sadly, you cannot customize the calendar tile. If someone knows of some homebrew application they can post in the comments. But you will have to have your phone rooted and/or developer unlocked to do it.

---

If you are looking for a 3rd Party app, I see a few in the Marketplace (just search for calendar). `Live Calendar` (4 stars from 89 reviews) looks like it might be what you are looking for, but I haven't used it so I can't vouch for it being awesome or actually consolidating event's from your accounts. It may just be another calendar you have to manually add events to.

Comment: Live Calendar as you said is just a calendar you add events to. It doesn't show up like a nice, clear tile the way the default calendar does. I'll keep looking and in the meantime wait for more suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What I want on the Calendar live tile is an option to show Tasks which need to be done soon, in the same way it shows events.

Comment: +1 for good info, but .... *is configured as to how Microsoft deems best according to the research and usability studies it has done* - holy cow. I took one look at the built-in calendar and it was pretty clear that noone studied anything. It's simply an incomplete programming exercise by some MS internal.